# regular expression with php to extract

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression what would search at the beginning of my string if there is a number followed a percent sign and extract it.

```
$string = "20% - some text";

preg_match('/^[0-9]+%$/',$string);
```

should return 20%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `$matches` argument:

```
$string = "20% - some text";
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/^([0-9]+%)/', $string, $matches)) {
     print_r($matches);
}
```